# Java Enum List from Class

Tags: java, enums

How do I go from a `Class` object to a list of enums generically?

i.e.

```
public static <T extends Enum> List<T> getList(Class<T> clazz)
```

I cant find a way to get to the `values()` method

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`Class#getEnumConstants()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants%28%29) returns the enum constants (type-safe).

So,

```
public static <T extends Enum> List<T> getList(Class<T> clazz) {
    return Arrays.asList(clazz.getEnumConstants());
}
```