# Enumerating Strings in Java with For Loop

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop, enumeration

Having trouble getting this for loop w/ enumerated strings to compile, I don't know what I'm missing to make it work. I prefer using for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {} but it doesn't work well for strings. Any advice is appreciated.

```
import java.util.*`

  public class Main { 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        Enumeration<String> Names; 
        Vector<String> cNames = new Vector();
        Names.add("string1"); 
        Names.add("string2"); 
        Names.add("string3"); 
        Names.add("string4"); 
        Names.add("string5");
        Names = cNames.elements();
        for (Names : cNames.elements())
        { 
            System.out.println(names); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: `for (String names : Names.elements())` - and you have a `Vector` with that name - you can't also name `Enumeration` `Names` (which looks like a class, not a variable).

Comment: And you aren't using generics, and you shouldn't use `Vector` or `Enumeration`...

Answer (score 0):

Names is already defined in scope. 
You have 
`Enumeration Names`
and
`Vector Names`

you might want to name them differently, and naming convention should start with lower case.

Comment: I edited it, missed a typo from my IDE code. Stack Overflow doesn't show my <String>s after "Enumeration" & "Vector" either

Comment: You want to instantiate Your typed enumeration.
`Enumeration <String> Names = new Enumeration<String>() {}`

Comment: This question talks about List of Enums 
Which is what i assume you're trying to do . A Vector of Enum values

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849529/java-enum-list-from-class